# Visual Studio Team Service: TF31002 Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

I have VS2013 Ultimate Update 5 and VS2015 Enterprise Update 1 installed on the same machine, Windows Server 2012 R2. Using VS2013 I'm able to connect to VSTS without anyn issues, however with VS2015 I'm getting the below connection failure:
[image]

Any help on how I can resolve this issues is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While connecting, I was putting the project name also as part of the server URL.
It was a silly mistake but got connected after removing the project name from the URL.

Answer (score 3):

There are no other different settings for VS2015. If you can work with VS2013, then it should also be work in VS2015. Try to reinstall the VS2015 first.

If it still no work, to narrow down this issue you can try below ways:

- Check Event Log to see whether there are some useful information.
- Delete Cookies and clear IE cache.
- [Clear TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) in the  %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team
     Foundation\x.0\Cache folder
- Run VS2015 in Administrator Mode.
- Delete all credentials from **Windows Credential Manager** (and remove
  Link Online ID)
- Delete [this folder](http://www.cnblogs.com/CuteNet/p/3556276.html) in the registry (just “TokenStorage” –
  nothing else)

Comment: I wouldn't think there would be different settings between VS2013 and VS2015. I'm buggered by this error myself. I've tried all the above mentioned steps but unfortunately none of them helped.

Comment: It was really weird. I used every  tactic I could think of. Could you set up a same environment on another machine to see if it works? And on your machine, try to uninstall  VS2013 and keep VS2015 only to see if it works. PS:  A friendly reminder : (Your personal information is not fully covered in the picture. `Team Foundation Server url: xxx` )

Comment: Hi Patrick, appreciate the response. Setting up a new environment will take me some time. I think I have to park this issue. It's not the end of the world, I can use VS2013 for source control for now.

Comment: I had 1 user experiencing this on 1 machine. Following the instructions in the clear TFS cache link fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the default port was 8080 when adding the new server.  I change it to port 80 and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per Nathan I tried to remove the project name from URL and it worked. for others you may not knowing the project name from the URL so keep removing the sub directory from right and try.